# I have a question that is the same as another user but they formulated theirs poorly

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, unclear

**My case is this one :**

- I have a very specific question regarding some behaviours of a tool.
- I see someone that has stumbled across the **exact same problem** *(there can be no mistake on that point)* 3 years ago
- I consider that their question is incomplete or misleadingly formulated

  - hence the absence of answers for their question

**Should I**

- Ask a new question with a more appropriate formulation ?
- Edit their question so that the issue is more clearly revealed (and put a bounty on it so that it gets more attention)?

**Some more context**

I mean their question is not all bad, it's rather clear what they ask and they even points to the official documentation (which also is misleading), but it does not reflect correctly the extreme test cases that would reveal what is wanted and and why the tool does not act as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question cannot be closed as a duplicate of another question that doesn't have any answers. The system will not allow it.

In most cases, I would go on and post a question of my own.

Editing the other one would also be an option, but unless it's a super-simple one-line question, you would likely be bringing so much new content to the table that it would alter the existing questions in ways that the OP may not have intended.

Comment: If you do get an answer it'd be nice if you flagged the other question as a duplicate so that people coming to that can find an answer to their question.